# File download is not working in using the ESAPI library

Tags: java, jsp, download, veracode, esapi

I am using the ESAPI for download the file (due to security reason only ESAPI is accepted). so please find my below code.

```
response.setContentType("application/msexcel");

ESAPI.httpUtilities().addHeader(response, "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testfile.xls");
```

When I click on download, the downloaded file is coming with proper content but the file extension and file name is not acceptable.

**Example** : When I click on the below url : http://localhost:8080/searchTest

***Expected*** file name as per the above case : testfile.xls

***Actual*** file name on download is : searchTest
(where the 'searchTest' is the url)

Could someone help me on how to pass the filename and extension in ESAPI ?

Thanks in advance,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really looked at this much and it probably doesn't make any difference (at least if you are using a Microsoft browser for testing this), but I the correct HTTP response header value `Content-Type` for downloading .xls Excel files is "**application/vnd.ms-excel**" and not "**application/msexcel**". So, I would try that first, just in case. [See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types for further details about .xlsx format.]

Secondly, can you confirm that it indeed is ESAPI that is causing this by changing you code to try it without ESAPI; e.g.,

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testfile.xls");
```

and retest it. (And technically, since there is no tainted input in your `Content-Disposition` header, you really don't *need* ESAPI for this particular case, although that would change if you were to accept a filename provided by the user.) If it still doesn't work without ESAPI, you at least know that it's not ESAPI that is causing it, and that's worth something. Likewise if it is ESAPI causing it.

Lastly, the other thing I would check would be to ensure that you don't have multiple `Content-Type` or `Content-Disposition` response headers going back to the user's browser. You can examine that from an intercepting proxy such as OWASP ZAP or Portswigger's Burp Suite or by using your browser's built-in development tools (e.g., F12 in Chrome; not sure what the shortcut is for Firefox). If there are multiple Content-Type headers or Content-Disposition headers that have different values, that could also be causing what you are observing.

Anyhow, let us know what you find out and we can try helping you further.